# Compiler complaining on a missing namespace which is the name of the class

Tags: c#, enums, namespaces

I have the following:

```
// Generator.cs
namespace MRP
{
    public class Generator
    {
        public enum ModeGeneration
        {
            ByRequest,
            ByCommit
        }
    }
}

// CustomerOrderWrapper.cs
namespace MRP
{
    class CustomerOrderWrapper
    {
        readonly ModeGeneration _mode;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error that the namespace name 'ModeGeneration' could not be found. Both classes are under MRP namespace, why the compiler is complaining on 'ModeGeneration' namespace?

Comment: What about `class CustomerOrderWrapper : Generator`? Probably you need to extend `Generator` class in `CustomerOrderWrapper` to access the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message again. It should say something like "can't find class or namespace ModeGeneration", and it's correct, there is no class/namespace named `ModeGeneration`, maybe you want `Generator.ModeGeneration`?

As an inner class, `Generator.ModeGeneration` is the whole type name, and you can't omit the outer class name, because you can define a few inner classes with the same name in C# like this:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class One
    {
        public class Bar { }
    }

    class Another
    {
        public class Bar { }
    }
}
```

You can see `Bar` is ambiguous. You should use `One.Bar` and `Another.Bar` instead.

Comment: Are you saying that in my example above where the enum is inside a class is similar than having a class inside a class in this context? If I had a property instead of the enum, I wouldn't get a compiling error.

Comment: It is not an ambigous issue, it is not found because the enum was defined inside the class (not sure if it was intened or a faulure). Roman and Abhishek got it right.

Comment: @bradbury9 I'm explaining "why they design it like this", or say "why the outer class name can't be omitted".

Comment: @ehh The type name of inner enums/classes is `Outer.Inner`, not `Inner`. And I explained why the `Outer.` part can't be omitted.

Comment: Thank you, this was the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are in the same namespace, but `enum ModeGeneration` is also inside `Generator` class. So either:

- Put the `enum` outside the `Generator` class and use it as you have

or

- Prefix `ModeGeneration` in CustomerOrderWrapper.cs with Generator - `Generator.ModeGeneration`

Answer (score 1):

That is because your enum is defined in the class. Change the code as follows:

```
namespace MRP
{
    class CustomerOrderWrapper
    {
        readonly Generator.ModeGeneration _mode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two method to solve this problem

Method 1) You can use class name put in front of enum

```
namespace MRP
{
    public class Generator
    {
        public enum ModeGeneration
        {
            ByRequest,
            ByCommit
        }
    }
}

// CustomerOrderWrapper.cs
namespace MRP
{
    class CustomerOrderWrapper
    {
        readonly Generator.ModeGeneration _mode;
    }
}
```

Method 2) You can bring enum from in class to out namespace

```
namespace MRP
{
public enum ModeGeneration
        {
            ByRequest,
            ByCommit
        }
    public class Generator
    {

    }
}

// CustomerOrderWrapper.cs
namespace MRP
{
    class CustomerOrderWrapper
    {
        readonly ModeGeneration _mode;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.